# insert records in a table from a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem, I need to put the records from the student table if the records of the vote_logs does not exist [image: here's the data structure]
and put it on the unvoted logs but don't know what the next will be

here's is my sql that I've done:

```
 $stud = mysql_query(" SELECT st.* FROM student st LEFT  JOIN vote_logs sv ON st.idno = sv.idno AND st.syearid = sv.syearid
    WHERE sv.idno IS NULL AND st.syearid = '$no' AND user_type='3'") or die(mysql_error());
```

should I insert or update? but if I use insesrt I should have values like saving but I want that will automatic? is this possible?

Comment: this is more of a sql question than only php, sir

Comment: you can set a cron job that execute some query every X minutes so it would do it automatically but why not instead of having 2 tables have just 1 with another column which would be 1bit that indicates the vote/unvoted ?

Comment: that's okey, I should put a status like 1 is the voted and 2 is the unvoted, but in the end of the voting if i click lock(time is up) then it will autosave the student who didn;t vote is that possible ? student already store in the database

Comment: 1 bit is 0 and 1 but yes the same point. and you could set the default value to unvoted and then if he voted before times up - then update to voted

Comment: can you have an example code?

Comment: example code of what ? I just gave you an idea on how you could improve your data structure,I cant really tell the point of the 'unvoted' logs , why you would want to save something that didn't happen ?

Comment: cause I want to display student who voted and notnoved by year

Answer (score 0):

You should create a view that will provide you with the same functionality without coping data and keeping your schema normalised:

```
CREATE VIEW unvoted_logs AS
SELECT st.* 
FROM student st 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vote_logs sv 
                  WHERE st.idno = sv.idno 
                     AND st.syearid = sv.syearid)
  AND sv.idno IS NULL 
  AND st.syearid = '$no' 
  AND user_type='3'
```